# Cant play transparent webm in three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

You can have transparent materials in three js, and transparent videos exist in the form of webm. I have a transparent webm Im trying to feed into a material, but I get 2 unsatisfying results.

1. No transparency, even tho transparent = true
2. This - transparency but poor quality, using the video itself as an alpha map:
   [image]

Code:

```
var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
    //video.src = './src/images/sintel.mp4';
    video.src = './src/images/dancer1.webm';
    video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.autoload = true;
    // video.play();

    this.videoTex = video;


    var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, transparent: true, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var runnerGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5, 1, 1);
    runnerMaterial.transparent = true;
    runnerMaterial.alphaMap = texture;
    // runnerMaterial.alphaMap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    // runnerMaterial.alphaMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    // runnerMaterial.alphaMap.repeat.y = 1;
    var runner = new THREE.Mesh(runnerGeometry, runnerMaterial);
```

How can I play a transparent video?

Comment: if your video is transparent already, you don't need to mess with it further at run time.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `alphaMap = texture;` because the alphaMap reads the green channel to determine opacity, as outlined [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.alphaMap). That's why you're getting that weird transparency; it's reading the green channel.

You're setting the format to `THREE.RGBFormat` (which is already the default, you can see it [in its source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/textures/VideoTexture.js#L12)), so if you want the alpha channel to be taken into consideration, you'll have to update that property to `THREE.RGBAFormat`;

And finally, don't forget to set the material's AlphaTest property to a sensible value, maybe 0.5 would work: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.alphaTest